# Case - Avoid stamping of current day when Case is Completed

Tags: case

In our case implementation, we are seeing "ClosedDate" on Case object automatically setting to Current date when the case's status becomes "Completed".

This looks like the standard functionality.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior i.e avoid setting of close date when the case status becomes completed ?

We could not even update this field (ClosedDate) to NULL as this is a system field.

Comment: Why do you want to skip having the ClosedDate field populated?

Answer (score 1):

Being that your business logic is counterintuitive to typical use of a Close Date, I suggest you create a new field and hide the original one from your layouts.

Comment: Layouts aren't enough. Best to hide it by Profiles (field level security) too or you'll have many interesting reports to debug ;)